# How to update tables in multiple schema in a database with a single changeset using liquibase for a multi-tenant application

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, liquibase, multi-tenant

I have a database with multiple schemas with same tables.

Inorder to update a particular schema "tenant1" below syntax can be used

```
<changeSet id="1660156908997-1" author="manu">
        <addColumn schemaName="tenant1" tableName="question">
            <column name="weightage" type="INT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Inorder to update two schemas viz., "tenant1" and "tenant2", below command can be used,

```
<changeSet id="1660156908997-1" author="manu">
        <addColumn schemaName="tenant1" tableName="question">
            <column name="weightage" type="INT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
        <addColumn schemaName="tenant2" tableName="question">
            <column name="weightage" type="INT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
</changeSet
```

But can we automate this and update ***all schemas*** with a ***single entry*** inside `changeset`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [changelog parameters](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html)?

What I would do is to parameterise the changes and then for each of your tenant definitions in your application execute the same changelog but with different parameters.

ChangeLog could look like this:

```
<changeSet id="1660156908997-1-${tenant}" author="manu">
        <addColumn schemaName="${tenant}" tableName="question">
            <column name="weightage" type="INT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: how do you add more than 1 schema in the above scenario? ```<property  name="tenant"  value="tenantA, tenanB"/> ``` this will give error..

Comment: you should do it in loop, not together. Try to loop through your datasources.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to loop using above approach? I do not see in the documentation.

Comment: I don't know how are you creating datasources. So maybe add some code where you define datasources. I mean spring datasources.

Comment: but we need to add the looping concept inside changeset right? Inside changelog file.. How to add the looping code for more than 1 schema? I understand your approach of adding a schema name using property tag. But how to do it using loop?

Comment: no, you would need to do loop inside java where you define your datasources. That's the idea of having the same parameterised changelog for all of your datasources. You would just define different parameters for each of your datasources.

Comment: Using java will not help me here... I am trying to find out the way to apply the same changeset on all available schemas in a database using liquibase. As I mentioned in the above question, I can do it using a separate changeset for each schema, but I want to explore if any option is available in liquibase.